# aspnet_merge single assembly not using latest DLL code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, aspnet-merge

I have a web site created in VS2010 that I merge into a single assembly using aspnet_merge. I recently made a small change to one of the compiled ascx pages, but the merged single assembly doesn't reflect that change.

To test further, I manually opened up the pre-merge ascx page DLL assembly to check that the change was present after publishing, and it's there. Before compiling, I build and then publish the site; the only option I have checked is "use fixed naming and single page assemblies". After merging (done from command line with v7.0A, no options specified), the merged assembly is created without incident, but without the change present.

It seems like the merge is taking some cached version of the website, rather than the latest updates - so I deleted any temporary files with no luck. IS there another reason the merged DLL might be missing the latest code change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. To speed up the merge process, I had placed the command into a batch file. Turns out, don't keep another assembly with the same name as the one getting merged (even if the merged files are in a different directory) in the same location as the batch file you're using.

Added the log parameter to the merge command and saw that the process will use a file in the same location as the batch command file and merge that in instead of the targeted code in the original command.